# How to properly use an If statement in PowerApps when trying to toggle visibility of an element?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-selected-items

I would like to toggle the visible property of a button that is nested in a Gallery in my PowerApp.

What I tried to was to go off of whether the parent was selected. I placed this formula inside the Visible property.

ink its a type issue, but I am not sure what is the best way to fix this.

```
If(Parent.Selected = true, true, false)
```

I received an "Invalid argument type" error on the "=" operator, so I think that perhaps I have a type mismatch or some other issue.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like an idiot, because about 5 minutes after I asked the question I figured out the answer.

All I had to do was to use the followng as the conditional statement:

```
ThisItem.IsSelected
```

The full solution being:

```
If(ThisItem.IsSelected,true,false)
```

Maybe this can help another rookie too :)

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, because `ThisItem.IsSelected` evaluates to `true`/`false`, you can shorten your code to just `ThisItem.IsSelected`. You can do this for any statements that evaluate to t/f.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could also simplify this by using `ThisItem.IsSelected` for the visible property of the button.

Comment: yeah, thats better.